# Prove a basic result in modular arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I’ve been taught that if $a \equiv b$ and $c \equiv d \pmod {m}$, then $a +c \equiv b+d \pmod{m}$ and $ac \equiv bd \pmod {m}$. But I would like to know how one can  prove it. Can you give me a hint? Thank you.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) for proofs of the basic rules of congruence arithmetic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $a \equiv b$ and $c \equiv d \pmod {m}$, then there exist integers $k$ and $h$ such that $a = b + km$ and $c = d + hm$.

---

Whence, 
$$a+c = b+d + (k+h)m;$$ 
thus, $a +c \equiv b+d \pmod {m}$.

In addition,
$$\begin{align} ac &= bd+dkm +bhm + khm^2 
\\ & = bd + (dk + bh + khm)m;\end{align}$$ 
thus, $ac \equiv bd \pmod {m}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. (Also, thank you for using the line to separate the hint from the complete solution. I figured the whole proof out when I looked at the hint and then checked it :))

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

- $$ \\ a \equiv  b \pmod m, c \equiv d \pmod m \Rightarrow  m \mid  a − b , m \mid c − d \Rightarrow  m \mid (a-b)+(c-d) \\ \Rightarrow m \mid (a+c)-(b+d) \Rightarrow a+c \equiv (b+d) \pmod m $$
- $$\\ a \equiv b \pmod m, c \equiv d \pmod m \Rightarrow m \mid a − b, m \mid c − d \\ \Rightarrow  m \mid  (a − b)c + (c − d)b \Rightarrow  m \mid  ac − bd \Rightarrow  ac \equiv bd \pmod m$$